# How to fix "Fatal error: Index out of range" in my thread

Tags: swift

I wrote this code, but when I try to execute it I have an error: "**Fatal error: index out of range**".

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantPageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var cell:[Bool] = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cardTableView: UITableView!
    
    let pictures: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named:"cinnamon lounge.jpg")!,UIImage(named:"thunapaha.jpg")!,UIImage(named:"Araliya.jpg")!,UIImage(named:"lakdevi.jpg")!,UIImage(named:"burdubai.jpg")!]
    let titles: [String] = ["Cinnamon Loung Restaurant","Tunapaha Restaurant","Araliya Restaurant","Lak Dew Reastaurant"]
   
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ _tableView:UITableView,  numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictures.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ _tableView:UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
         let cell = _tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCell
        
        cell.configure(picture: pictures[indexPath.row], title: titles[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's obvious, `titles.count != pictures.count`. You should be using a model instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create a model:

```
struct Restaurant {
    var title: String
    var picture: UIImage
}
```

Then use `Restaurant` model in `RestaurantPageViewController` array to populate `tableView`.

```
class RestaurantPageViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardTableView: UITableView!

    let restaurants = [
        Restaurant(title: "Cinnamon Loung Restaurant", picture: UIImage(named: "cinnamon lounge.jpg")!),
        Restaurant(title: "Tunapaha Restaurant", picture: UIImage(named: "thunapaha.jpg")!),
        Restaurant(title: "Araliya Restaurant", picture: UIImage(named:"Araliya.jpg")!),
        Restaurant(title: "Lak Dew Reastaurant", picture: UIImage(named:"lakdevi.jpg")!)]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { restaurants.count }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCell
        cell.configure(restaurant: restaurants[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

Finally, modify `configure` method in `CardCell` to configure your cell.

```
class CardCell: UITableViewCell {
    func configure(restaurant: Restaurant) {
        // do config
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Struct instead

```
struct MyModel {
    let picture: UIImage?
    let title: String?
}
```

Then add this struct to array

```
let model = MyModel(picture: UIImage(named:"cinnamon lounge.jpg"), title: "123")
             
            var modelArray = [MyModel] ()
            modelArray.append(model)
```

And use this modelArray in tableView ...

Comment: Why optionals? All values are clearly non-optional.

Comment: some titles may have pictures ... or some pictures may have just titles ... thats why they are optional ...  there is no other reason sir :)

Comment: and this way we can avoid this `UIImage(named: "cinnamon lounge.jpg")!` force casting as well :)

Comment: @vadian can you please suggest anything on this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63109348/1780632

Answer (score 0):

you loaded 5 images into your pictures list and 4 titles into your titles list. When you access pictures[indexPath.row] and titles[indexPath.row], titles[indexPath.row] will throw an index out of range error when indexPath.row == 5 because you only have 4 string elements in 'titles'

tldr: add another title